Custom HTML Controls in Gantt Data Grid
We are using the AnyChart library, specifically the AnyGantt module (version: 8.12.1.1937 (2024-04-10)).  I am attempting to add custom controls inside the DataGrid portion of the chart.  I am able to add custom columns and include custom html controls in those grid cells.  However, the chart's built-in event handlers are preventing all attempts to click on the controls.  For example, when I attempt to click on a control (i.e. a textbox) in a cell, the chart's rowClick event is firing and not allowing the click to reach the control.  I can tab into the control, but I can't click on it.
I'm creating the column like so:
let colJunk = dataGrid.column(4);
colJunk.width(120);
colJunk.title().useHtml(true).text('<span style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 11px">MCP</span>');

I add the control in the column like so:
colJunk.labels().useHtml(true);
colJunk.labels().format('<input type="text" value="{%someData}"/>');

The data renders properly.  Inspecting the DOM, I can see that the controls are being rendered properly:
<input type="text" value="End of Line">

However, when I click on the text box, nothing happens.  It won't select the text box and allow me to type.  I assume the overall control's event handling framework is not allowing the control to receive the click.
Interestingly, if I press the tab key, it will highlight the nearest textbox control and I can enter text.  I just can't mouse-click into the control.
This needs to work for all types of controls:  textboxes, drop-downs, check boxes, etc.
I've tried enabling and disabling chart editing:
chart.edit(false);

I've also tried preventing default on the row click handler:
chart.listen("rowClick", function (e) { e.preventDefault() });

No luck.
In the docs, I see a suite of row events, connector events, and data tree events, but I don't see any events relating to data grid cells.
EDIT: In this example, I'm capturing the rowClick information, but I don't have a way to differentiate between controls.  It is explicitly giving focus to the appropriate textbox. I need to give focus to whichever control is clicked.
Link to Anychart Playground: https://playground.anychart.com/K9CjPBXI/2
Code:
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
  // The data used in this sample can be obtained from the CDN
  // https://cdn.anychart.com/samples/gantt-charts/human-resource-chart/data.js
  anychart.data.loadJsonFile(
    'https://cdn.anychart.com/samples/gantt-charts/human-resource-chart/data.json',
    function (data) {
      // create data tree
      var treeData = anychart.data.tree(data, 'as-table');

      // create resource gantt chart
      var chart = anychart.ganttResource();

      // set data for the chart
      chart.data(treeData);

      chart
        .rowSelectedFill('#D4DFE8')
        .rowHoverFill('#EAEFF3')
        // set start splitter position settings
        .splitterPosition(150);

      // get chart data grid link to set column settings
      var dataGrid = chart.dataGrid();

      // set first column settings
      dataGrid
        .column(0)
        .title('#')
        .width(30)
        .labels({ hAlign: 'center' });
      
      let colJunk1 = dataGrid.column(1);
      colJunk1.width(120);
      colJunk1.title().useHtml(true).text('<span style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 11px">Textboxes</span>');
      colJunk1.labels().useHtml(true).format('<input id="text_{%id}" type="text" value="row {%id} value"/>');
      
      let colJunk2 = dataGrid.column(2);
      colJunk2.width(120);
      colJunk2.title().useHtml(true).text('<span style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 11px">Dropdowns</span>');
      colJunk2.labels().useHtml(true).format(`<select id="select_{%id}">
          <option value="apple">Apple</option>
          <option value="banana">Banana</option>
          <option value="cherry">Cherry</option>
      </select>`);

      // Row click event
      chart.listen('rowClick', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const element = document.getElementById(`text_${e.index+1}`);
        if (element) element.focus();
      });

      // set container id for the chart
      chart.container('container');

      // initiate chart drawing
      chart.splitterPosition("250");
      chart.draw();

      // zoom chart to specified date
      chart.zoomTo(1171036800000, 1176908400000);
    }
  );
});


Please share a minimal reproducible example.

@Markus - See the added paragraph in the description above and this working example:  https://playground.anychart.com/K9CjPBXI/2

Not the whole story, but did you check https://playground.anychart.com/api/core/ui/_samples/anychart.core.ui.DataGrid.edit_get ?

Yes.  I've looked at those samples.  My example above is in the same code playground.  There are no samples that I could find that have multiple custom controls on a row.  If you found such a sample, please let me know!  Thanks for your assistance!
